# Paredit doesn't remove right paren on paredit-backward-kill-word

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, paredit

The buffer is "(|)". On Alt+Backspace which sends paredit-backward-kill-word, it only removes the left paren and leaves the buffer as "|)".
I thought it was a bug in Paredit or Emacs. But Alt+Backspace works exactly the same way in Clojure editor in IntelliJ IDEA. It made me think - is it a feature in Paredit? What's the point?

Comment: Sometimes a bug is just a bug:). This function bails with `backward-kill-word` when nothing useful can be done, that's what you're seeing here.

Comment: Also, I've made my own Paredit with blackjack and ... you know.
Have a look at https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Alt+d. Find paredit [cheatsheet](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/paredit-cheatsheet/blob/master/paredit.pdf?raw=true)